how to save image in Django project
when i try to create new employee in my project the instance has been save but image not.
here is my model,view and form from my django project
my model-
`class Emp(models.Model):
emp_first_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False)
emp_last_name=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=False)
emp_father_name=models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,default='')
emp_mother_name=models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=False,default='')
emp_photo=models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,upload_to='static/image/emp',)`

my view-
   `def EmpAdd(request):
       if request.method=='POST':
          form=EmpForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
      if  form.is_valid():
          form.save()
           messages.success(request,'New Employee has been added')
        else:
           messages.error(request,'There has been error')
      else:
      form=EmpForm()

  return render(request,'emp/emp_crt.html',{'form':form})`

my form -
  `class  EmpForm(ModelForm):
     class Meta:
      model=Emp
     fields='__all__'
     widgets={
     'emp_id':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',}),
     'emp_bod':DateInput(attrs={'type':'date','class':'form-control',}),
     'emp_first_name':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',}),
     'emp_last_name':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control',}),
     'emp_father_name':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
     'emp_mother_name':TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
     'emp_photo':FileInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
    }`

when i try to creat new employee in my django project, new employee has been created but image has not been saved.what should i do?

please can we see your template where the image URL logic is written for the saving process? Do you forget to install pillow, and can we see your static  dirs configuration for your image on both settings.py and urls.py?

Do you set a path for media files in your settings.py file ?

There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. Although, you missed the template file, there is where the problem lies. A pretty common mistake, missing enctype on your html form:
<form action="{% url 'reverse-url' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

Without it, file data is not attached to the form.
